# Print data of a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, jq

Print data of a file
This it the file content

```
{
 "nodes": {
    "server.xyz": {
      ":ip": "192.168.56.5",
      "ports": [],
      ":memory": 1024,
      ":bootstrap": "bootstrap-master.sh"
    },
    "client1.abc": {
      ":ip": "192.168.56.10",
      "ports": [],
      ":memory": 1024,
      ":bootstrap": "bootstrap-node.sh"
    },
    "client1.def": {
      ":ip": "192.168.56.15",
      "ports": [],
      ":memory": 1024,
      ":bootstrap": "bootstrap-node.sh"
    }
  }
}
```

I only want to print

**server.xyz**

**client1.abc**

**client2.def**

and this IP

**192.168.56.5**

**192.168.56.10**

**192.168.56.15**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/),

**Example**

```
{
 "nodes": {
  "server.local": {
  ":ip": "192.168.56.5",
  "ports": [],
  ":memory": 1024,
  ":bootstrap": "bootstrap-master.sh"
},
"client1.local": {
  ":ip": "192.168.56.10",
  "ports": [],
  ":memory": 1024,
  ":bootstrap": "bootstrap-node.sh"
},
"client1.local": {
  ":ip": "192.168.56.15",
  "ports": [],
  ":memory": 1024,
  ":bootstrap": "bootstrap-node.sh"
}
}}
```

And run,

```
cat file | jq -r '.nodes | keys[]'
```

**Output**

```
client1.abc
client1.def
server.xyz
```

**Edit:**

If you want `ip` as well,

```
cat file | jq -r '.nodes | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.":ip"] | @tsv'
```

Comment: thanks sir. by the, how about if I want to get the IP also, updated question

Answer (score 0):

you can execute the file as commands
and have echo in the file so like

````
 "nodes": {
    echo"server.xyz": {
     echo ":ip": "192.168.56.5",
     ```
and so on then you do
```eval $(cat file location)```
but i think the has to be in one line
````